# How to create PDF reports using XML and XSLT using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, xslt

I am curious to how can somebody generate a `PDF` file using `C#` and use `XML` and `XLST` as mark up language.

Do I need specific Libraries? - Also, I can't find anything on Google or Youtube on a tutorial to create a PDF file using XML as mark up and XLST as style using C#.

This is the idea:

- Create XML Mark up
- Use XLST to style XML
- C# to insert data into XML template e.g. `Contact name, telephone number..`. **(But not saving/overwrite the XML file - only to use as template)**
- Save it as PDF as output

Where can I start learning this? - Has anybody had experience in this field? If so, can do you direct me to achieve this goal?

Comment: Check the FastReport Open Source Project, https://github.com/FastReports/FastReport

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer Brilliant ! Appreciate your help

Comment: In terms of standards, you could use XSL FO or HTML+CSS to get to PDF